# retrieving the serial number of a USB keyboard under Windows

Tags: windows, hardware, usb

Many USB devices contain a unique serial number (which is actually a Unicode string) which the host can use in conjunction with the 16-bit vendor and product ID numbers to uniquely identify the device.

I'm trying to figure out how to write a Windows application that would be able to display a list of all USB human interface devices attached to the system.  The list would have one row for each HID, including system keyboards.  There would be columns in the list for the vendor ID, product ID, and serial number.

I can get a list of USB HIDs by calling `SetupDiGetClassDevs` with the GUID returned by `HidD_GetHidGuid` and looping through the result by repeatedly calling `SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces`.  I can then call `SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail` to get the path to each device, which I can open with `CreateFile`, so long as I am careful to request neither read nor write permission, which would be denied for a system keyboard.  From there I can get the vendor and product ID numbers by invoking `HidD_GetAttributes`.

What I'm having trouble figuring out is how to retrieve the serial number string.  When I search for solutions to this problem, I find a lot of information about how to get serial numbers for USB mass storage devices, but nothing that looks like it might apply to any other type of USB device.  I would be happy to discover either a generic method or a HID-specific method of retrieving the serial number string.

I have a feeling that the Win32 port of `libusb` could manage this without too much trouble, but unfortunately I need a solution that depends only on libraries that come with Windows, such as the `setupapi` and `hid` DLLs that contain the functions mentioned above.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the USBVIew source code that comes along with the DDK. The USBView tool displays serial number for any USB device, and the source is shipped with the DDK.

Answer (score 5):

It turns out that `HID.dll` defines a function called `HidD_GetSerialNumberString` that does exactly what I want, given the handle I got from `CreateFile` as described above.  Just tried it out and it works great.  There are also `HidD_GetManufacturerString` and `HidD_GetProductString` functions to retrieve the other string descriptors referred to in the device descriptor, and even a `HidD_GetIndexedString` to get an arbitrary string descriptor given its index (presumably because the HID descriptor is allowed to contain string descriptor indices).  I feel pretty silly now -- the answer was right there under my nose this whole time.

Thank you all for taking the time to read and answer my question!  I'm going to go ahead and accept Alphaneo's answer since it sounds quite promising, and in fact I was waiting for the DDK to download when I stumbled across this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried searching for the documentation of the HID definition of input records, output records and features records for Hid keyboards. This should show you the list of "things" you can get out/in of a keyboard through HID.

Also, I know it is possible to enumerate the HID record definition by software. I did something similar about 1 year ago, but I cannot remember the details at the top of my head. Doing so would allow you to see what the keyboard USB class is publishing as a standard interface.

I hope it can get you a few pointers to find out what you are looking for. Sorry I could not be more precise!

Comment: Unfortunately, a USB string descriptor is neither a HID input report, nor an output report, nor a feature report.  Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this book [USB Complete](http://www.lvr.com/usbc.htm). Chapter 4 Enumeration: How the Host Learns about Devices has the information you need.

[This page](http://www.lvr.com/usb.htm) has many links to information and for you links to libraries and utilities you can use.

Comment: It's a great book -- I own a copy of the third edition, and I'm sure I would never have gotten so far as even asking this question if I hadn't read it.  The chapter in question does indeed mention the information I'm trying to retrieve, though it doesn't seem to explain how to get at it from a Windows application.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `GetVolumeInformation` for getting the serial number of any hardware attached.