# Client's keyboard serial number to server/host

Tags: c#, .net

can anyone please suggest/route me to get the best place on how to get keyboard serial/product number that is connected to the client's machine, from a server/host in .net c#?

right now we use OPOS along with ActiveX but we don't want this be in our product anymore

cannot use ActiveX to connect to clients machine.

The keyboard I'll be using would be prehkeytec MCI series, I have gone through their API but it says they have OPOS compatibility which is obselete. The latest version of OPOS is POSready 7(this is what i saw during my research, I may be wrong also.) I really don't know how to use POSready 7 in my application.

Anyhelp really appreciated.

Comment: Can you use WMI? There is the `Win32_Keyboard` class which has a device id.

Comment: Keyboards don't have serial numbers.

Comment: @mikez i did that but we need to do something where everything has be handled on server side. If we use WMI there will be client's intervention which should not be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost certainly going something on the client machine p/invoking some lower-level Win32 stuff:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172516(v=vs.90).aspx
- [retrieving the serial number of a USB keyboard under Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723449/retrieving-the-serial-number-of-a-usb-keyboard-under-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to handle this on the `Client` side by sending the keyboard information over.

It looks like this can be done with `System.Management` to access the `Win32_Keyboard` properties. Take a look at this post:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17973/How-To-Get-Hardware-Information-CPU-ID-MainBoard-I

Comment: Already tried this but I need to do in such a way that everything has to be on the server side and there should be no client's intervention for this.